# Deploy application through wifi

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi

Is it possible to deploy android apk through wifi from one android device to rest of devices

which are connected to same network like Bulk Deployment

Comment: http://www.cnet.com/how-to/transfer-files-between-android-devices-over-wi-fi-with-tappouch/

Comment: Wow, it sounds like a virus if it does exist!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: It is possible to push the content via WiFi Direct from one device to another, or to download the files via WiFi using dedicated software if both devices are located in the same network. But *apk* installation is not possible from the code (however, it could be possible to achieve this if the phone is rooted, but this goes into a separate discussion).

Comment: More precisely, one can *initiate* the apk installation process from unprivileged code, but done this way it will require interactive user *confirmation*.